# How to get the user ID from MySQL/Maria DB?

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql, mariadb, userid

In PostgreSQL, for instance, the query `SELECT * FROM pg_user` return the `usesysid` column in which you can see the users IDs. So I can get the oldest/newest user from this table through this ID.

How can I do the same in Mysql and Maria DB?

I am surprised that there is no field that shows the creation date of each user in any driver.

Comment: There is not necessarily any relationship between MySQL/MariaDB "user" and OS "user".

Answer (score 2):

Listing the users should be as simple as:

```
select * from mysql.user
```

Column `user` give you the user id. Combined with `host`, this is the unique identifier of each account.

[Documentation for MariaDB](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/mysqluser-table/).

[Documentation for MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/user-names.html).

Please note, however, that MySQL / MariaDB do not track the date when users are created. A solution is to add a custom column to the `users` table that defaults to the current date:

```
ALTER TABLE mysql.users ADD date_created TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP;
```

Comment: It's always a bad idea to modify system tables which might end up in unexpected behaviors. In recent versions of MariaDB and MySQL privileges are stored in globals_priv and mysql.user is a view.

Answer (score 0):

Starting with MariaDB 10.4.1 the source for users and privileges is `mysql.global_privs` see [MariaDB Docu](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mysqlglobal_priv-table/).
Users, that are authorized by password have a property `password_last_changed`.
That's not the creation date you are looking for but can be a hint for the age of users entries, i.e.:

> | localhost | phpmyadmin     | {"access":0,"version_id":100515,"plugin":"mysql_native_password","authentication_string":"xxxx","password_last_changed":1660639196} |